# I'm having trouble with write in a file in windows?

Tags: c, winapi, file-io

I'm trying to create a text file and write to it, but when i open the text file the output came out wrong.

Sample:

```
Please enter number of students?
2
Please Enter details of the Students in the Following sequence: Name Age GPA
alex  18 3.2
dan  21 3.5
```

Output:

```
tttttttttkkkkkkkkksssssssssss
```

The code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>

struct Student {
    WCHAR name[20];
    int age;
    float gpa;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct Student St;
    int NumOfStu;
    printf("Please enter number of students\n");
    scanf("%d" , &NumOfStu);

    HANDLE f = CreateFile(L"d:\\SPR2.txt" , GENERIC_WRITE , 0 , NULL , CREATE_ALWAYS , FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL , NULL);
    if(f == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Could not Create The File\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Please Enter details of the Sutdents in the Following sequence: Name Age GPA\n");

    DWORD actual;

    for(int i=0 ;i<NumOfStu;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s %d %f" , &St.name , &St.age , &St.gpa );
        WriteFile(f ,  , sizeof(struct Student) , &actual , NULL); 
    }
    CloseHandle(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your call to  `WriteFile` looks real funny, there's a missing argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
    scanf("%s %d %f" , &St.name , &St.age , &St.gpa );
```

`name` already decays to a pointer, you shouldn't use `&` with it.

Also, it is a wide string, which scanf does not expect.  So you will get corruption.

Comment: I'm not sure this was helpful

Comment: @M.z: Did it not help you because you don't understand it, because you're not sure how to use this information to fix your program, or because you already knew this and your real program doesn't have these problems?

Answer (score 0):

In the WriteFile, where is lpBuffer? It looks like your missing that parameter, and you're
writing the poiner value, as pointed out in another answer.

from [WriteFileFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteFile(
  __in         HANDLE hFile,
  __in         LPCVOID lpBuffer,
  __in         DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  __out_opt    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
  __inout_opt  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);



  for(int i=0 ;i<NumOfStu;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s %d %f" , &St.name , &St.age , &St.gpa );
        WriteFile(f ,  , sizeof(struct Student) , &actual , NULL); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in your WriteFile call: I don't expect this compiled as is.

Assuming you've corrected that, your WriteFile call

```
WriteFile(f , (LPCVOID)&St, sizeof(struct Student) , &actual , NULL);
```

is writing the entire binary content of the structure. This is fine if you plan to read it back in the same way. But it won't make any sense if you open the file in a text editor. For example, the name field in Student will be written as 20 wide characters, including the null termination after the actual contents, and any junk that might have been in memory after the termination.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: it's an unnecessary cast but perhaps not a useless one. I wanted to emphasize that WriteFile takes a void* and doesn't understand the internal layout of a struct Student.

Comment: It's worse than useless, it's downright harmful.  If you forgot the `&`, then the cast may cause it to compile without warnings and treat integral data as a pointer, causing data corruption at runtime.  If you leave off the cast, the compiler will properly accept any pointer, but reject non-pointer variables.